# Use `useQuery` hook the same way as `useMutation` fails

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, apollo, react-apollo

Using React and Apollo React hooks

```
import { useCallback, useState } from "react";
import { useMutation, useSubscription, useQuery } from "@apollo/react-hooks";
```

I got a function `useChannel` in which I have hooks with all my graphql mutations.
Each mutation is imported and then declared as a constant like so:

```js
const [addExportChannel] = useMutation(AddExportChannelMutation);
```

Which I consume in the returned function of the hook like so

```js
  const onAddImportChannel = useCallback(
    async (props) => {
      try {
        const data = await addImportChannel({
          variables: {
            shopId,
            name: props.name,
            url: props.url,
            filetype: props.filetype
          }
        });
...
```

When I try to do the same with `useQuery` it fails saying `useQuery` is not iterable.
`TypeError: useQuery is not a function or its return value is not iterable`

```js
 const [FeedProcess] = useQuery(GetFeedProcessQuery);
...
 const onFeedProcess = useCallback(
    async (props) => {
      try {
        const data = await FeedProcess({
          variables: { shopId, feedId: props.feedId }
        });
...
```

What am I missing here, trying to figure out what is so different in the two hooks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because useQuery is called immediately you cannot store it like this (`const [FeedProcess] = useQuery(GetFeedProcessQuery);`). But apollo's got useLazyQuery that can be stored like you did. If you'd like to store and invoke it later, use useLazyQuery instead.

Answer (score 1):

You should de-structure the props from useQuery hook like so:

```js
const {data, loading, error} = useQuery(GetFeedProcessQuery);
```

Comment: This way the query is called straight away, but I guess there is no way around that. The addExportChannel from the useMutation example, will only run when I call it in a nested function. I can not nest the useQuery on it's own since that will go against hook rules. 
I wanted to use FeedProcess as the trigger for useQuery.